# How to change user.getid in firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image]

```
public void register(final String username, final String fullname, String email, String password) {
    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    pd.show();
                    FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                    String userID ="Queenlab@"+firebaseUser.getUid();
                    //  circleIV.setImageDrawable(drawable2);

                    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID);
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("id",userID);
                    map.put("username", username.toLowerCase());
                    map.put("fullname", fullname);
                    map.put("imageurl", "https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.PXxWJplK9ObsWdxdFCqLOwHaE8?pid=ImgDet&rs=1");
                    map.put("bio", "");
                    map.put("instgram", "");    

                    reference.setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "Register sccessful sending Email Verification", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                sendVerificationEmail();
                                auth.signOut();
                                Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I tried to answer below, but going forward please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow the guidance in there. It might also be good to read up on what a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) is.

Answer (score 0):

The UID of a user is determined by the authentication provider. It can't be set from client-side application code, as that would be a security risk.

If you want to determine the UID of your users, you can [implement your own provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth). Note that this will include writing code that runs in a trusted environment, such as a server that you control, or Cloud Functions/Cloud Run.

Alternatively you can implement a mapping from the UID of the user to whatever ID system you want to use in your database.